# Extract first date from a string within a column

Tags: r

The string below is in a notes column where it may appear at the beginning, mid or bottom of note. There may be other dates within the notes but I am only looking to extract the date with PlanA within the string to create a new column.

```
"12/8/22 Matthew: PlanA (Include in Review file)"
```

Desired output is date into a new column e.g. `12/8/22`
New to R but I tried the below and got this

```
Error: unexpected '\\' in: mutate(NoteDate = substring(DF$Notes,"(^.*"\\d+/\\d+/\\d+"\s\\w+:\s PlanA"))
```

Comment: There's a few issues here - you shouldn't need to reference columns with `$` like `DF$Notes` if you're chaining commands together, the name of the dataset is passed through to `mutate` - e.g.:  `DF %>% mutate(NoteDate = Notes)` . Secondly, `substring` does not use regular expressions. I think you possibly want `str_extract` from the *stringr* package instead.

Comment: Try this: `stringr::str_replace(x, '^.*?(\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+)\\s\\w+:\\s+PlanA.*', "\\1")`

Comment: @SuNa, thanks that code worked